# Magento 2: How to set "Maximum Login Failures to Lockout Account" different Role wise?

Tags: magento2, login, user-roles, account

We have this

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-admin.html

> In the '**Maximum Login Failures to Lockout Account**' field, enter the
> number of times a user can try to log in to the Admin before the
> account is locked. By default, six attempts are allowed. Leave the
> field empty for unlimited login attempts.

How do I set this for different role wise?

I have multiple user roles and I want to set it different each role wise?

For example:

```
Role A : 10
Role B : 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no default setting for admin role  wise ;

For Customer customer

> Store==>Configuration=> CustomerConfig ==>Maximum Login Failures to
> Lockout Account:10+

For Admin(all):

> Store==>Configuration=>Advanced=>Admin ==> Security=>Maximum Login
> Failures to Lockout Account=6++